# Making TF-IDF vector from one hot encoding in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a data frame extracted as one hot encoding as following

```
entity,wordnet_country_108544813,wordnet_political_campaign_10747292,wordnet_area_108497294, wordnet_location_100027167,wordnet_extremity_108568978,wordnet_physical_entity_100001930,wordnet_worker_109632518  
Ukraine,1,0,1,1,0,1
Paris,0,0,1,1,0,1
```

I want to make TF/IDF of the above entity and use vector for entity Ukraine, Paris in BERT model, but I tried TF-IDF from sklearn, but it's not working. The expected output as follows

```
Ukraine, 0.0119811,0.03392,0.0122609,0,0.00605333,0 
Paris, 0.00702039, 0.00186334,0,0.0104439,0.00266024,0
```

Comment: Please provide the code you tried, versions of packages, and any tracebacks. It's hard to help if we can't recreate the problem. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)